# Hibernate envers not working in Arquillian

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss-arquillian, hibernate-envers

I'am trying to perform some Arquillian tests regarding hibernate entity versioning system.

Whatever i do, auditing tables (_AUD) are not being created and envers is not working in general.

I searched other posts and made sure i follow the same version on both hibernate-core and envers.

Here is my pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>sandbox</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>sandbox</name>

<properties>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <version.jee.api>7.0</version.jee.api>
    <version.ejb>3.2</version.ejb>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>

    <!-- other plugin versions -->
    <version.compiler.plugin>3.1</version.compiler.plugin>
    <version.ear.plugin>2.10</version.ear.plugin>
    <version.ejb.plugin>2.3</version.ejb.plugin>
    <version.surefire.plugin>2.16</version.surefire.plugin>
    <version.hibernate5-ddl-maven-plugin>2.0.4</version.hibernate5-ddl-maven-plugin>

    <!-- Other libs -->
    <version.deltaspike>1.8.0</version.deltaspike>
    <modelMapper.version>1.1.0</modelMapper.version>


    <!--  Hibernate -->
    <hibernate.core.version>5.2.11.Final</hibernate.core.version>
    <hibernate.modelgen.version>5.2.11.Final</hibernate.modelgen.version>
    <hibernate.annotations.version>3.5.6-Final</hibernate.annotations.version>
    <hibernate.javax.persistence.version>1.0.0.Final</hibernate.javax.persistence.version>
    <hibernate.validator.version>6.0.2.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
    <hibernate.jpa.api.version>1.0.0.Final</hibernate.jpa.api.version>


</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.javax.persistence.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.narayana.jta</groupId>
        <artifactId>narayana-jta</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.1.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-wls-remote-12.1.2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Alpha3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-persistence-integration-tests</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Alpha7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Logging -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

and the Arquillian base test class:

```
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Archive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.Maven;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;
import java.io.File;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
    public class BaseTest {

    @Inject
    protected Logger logger;

    @Inject
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    protected UserTransaction utx;

    @Deployment(name = "SandboxTest")
    public static Archive<?> createTestArchive() {

        File[] lib1 = Maven.configureResolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
                .importRuntimeDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();

        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "SandboxTest2.war")
                .addAsLibraries(lib1)
                .addPackages(true, PersonT.class.getPackage(), EMProducer.class.getPackage(), BaseTest.class.getPackage())
                .addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
                .addAsResource("log4j.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource("weblogic.xml");
    }

    @Before
    public void startTransaction() throws Exception {
        utx.begin();
        em.joinTransaction();
    }

    @After
    public void commitTransaction() throws Exception {
        utx.commit();
        em.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course I have also added The "@Audited" annotation in my entities

Comment: Have you tried to do a do a system.out.println of the webarchive generated by shirkwrap (webarchive.toString(true)) to validate that all the libs are added correctly.

Comment: Thank you that helped me a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. A pleasure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of a comment, I found the solution.
I had to import all pom dependencies, not only the runtime ones!

The correct ShrinkWrap setup is:

```
@Deployment(name = "SandboxTest")
public static Archive<?> createTestArchive() {


    File[] lib1 = Maven.configureResolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")  
.importCompileAndRuntimeDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();


    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "SandboxTest.war")
            .addAsLibraries(lib1)  //add lib1
            .addPackages(true, PersonT.class.getPackage(),
                    PersonDTO.class.getPackage(),
                    PersonRepository.class.getPackage(),
                    CurrentUser.class.getPackage(),
                    Service.class.getPackage(),
                    BaseTest.class.getPackage())
            .addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsResource("log4j.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource("weblogic.xml");
}
```